# How to specify WCF operation to call at run time?

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I have a WCF WF web service (workflow service 4.0) and each operation of this service has the same signature, but different name.

My system receives an event `{int eventType, int entityId}` and needs to dispatch that event to an operation on the web service I mentioned above using configuration.

E.g. suppose I have config file (which maps eventType to an operation name):

```
1 -> "StartOrder"
5 -> "StopOrder"
8 -> "ProcessPaymet"
9 -> "RepartFraud"
```

so if I receive `eventType` equal to 5 I need to do something like:

```
string operationName = eventTypeToOperationMap[eventType];
new ChannelFactory<IMyWebService>().CreateChannel().CallOperation(operationName, entityId);
```

and IMyWebService has a method:

```
void StopOrder(int entityId);
```

Background: `IMyWebService` is a windows workflow foundation 4.0 workflow service. I want to be able to add new entry point to the web service, and changing config file for event dispatcher, without having to recompile event dispatcher.

Comment: Hi THX, could you consider refactoring your service interface so that it takes an int eventType as an input parameter? Your service code could then branch accordingly. It would mean moving away from a fine-grained service interface to a more generic one. I didn't put this as an answer as it doesn't answer the actual question you asked but I thought it might be an alternative approach that could get you out of a hole.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to call another service (or another operation on your service) which takes the eventType as a parameter. Inside that operation, you will create a new channel and call the corresponding operation (just like you're already doing).